# What type of endian does a Macbook Pro with M1 Max use?

Tags: macos, memory, endianness, apple-m1

Does the new M1 Max ARM Chip use little endian or big endian to store hex?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As from this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/porting-your-macos-apps-to-apple-silicon

> Note Both Apple silicon and Intel-based Mac computers use the
> little-endian format for data, so you don’t need to make endian
> conversions in your code. However, continue to minimize the need for
> endian conversions in custom data formats that you create.